# How to force a link on a new line?

Tags: html, css

I have a sequence of html  links, some long and some short.
Now my problem is I don't want the link to break to a new line in the middle, I want it to just go to the new line.
Right now some of my links (a sequence of words which can be 5 or 6 words long) have the annoying behaviour of breaking to a new line right in the middle.

Makes sense?

can you help? Thx!

Comment: No, doesn't make sense to me. `I want it to go to a new line.` `My links have the annoying behavior of breaking to a new line.` Post some HTML and CSS please.

Comment: Could you post the html you're using?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here's an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcQ8m/).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with `<nobr><a ...</a></nobr>`, which is deprecated as Sn0opy pointed out.

You should do it via CSS:

```
a { 
    white-space: nobreak; 
}
```

Comment: If you want to stay with the standards, thats right. Fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Well, yeah, of course it's still working because of downward compatibility, but you shouldn't use it anymore.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. That's why I already fixed it in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the anchor's display attribute in css to block. Here is a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/v9dbF/3/).